# SUMIF EXCEL 2013 - Multiple criteria

Tags: excel, concatenation, excel-2013, sumifs

I have a spreadsheet that has 2 sheets on is detailed with names and hours over a period of 2 years, which includes a column for the month ie

Sheet1
Year      Mth    Name   Qty   Area

The other sheet has it as summary ie

Sheet2
Year  Mth   Name Area1   Area2  Area3  Area4 Area5

I have concatenated Year Mth Name & Area in sheet1, but how do I get it to look up the year, mth, name, area and return the sum of the qty

Thanks

Comment: Use SUMIFS not SUMIF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

This should give you an idea what to do:

```
 =SUMPRODUCT(
 (Input[Year]=[Year])*
 (Input[Mth]=[Mth])*
 (Input[Name]=[Name])*
 (Input[Area]=$K$1)*
 Input[Qty])
```